# Browser freezes on generating large JSON structure using jQuery/JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, performance

I have to create a json structure which contains 1000s of entries, What happens is it freezes browser for few moments until the process completes. Is there any performance factor depends on approach. I create the json and entry by below approach

```
resultJson=[];
//each loop
entry = {};
entry['id1']=var1;
entry['id2']=var2;
resultJson.push(entry);
```

How to avoid browser freeze on the process of generating json or is there any better approach to create/add json entries ?

Comment: Do it on the server side

Comment: You can call the expensive function using `setTimeout` with a small delay, it then runs as if it was asynchronous and shouldn't block the UI.

Comment: yes pawel .but timeout trick again will increase the total time for processing. will give it a try anyways !

Comment: martynas, unfortunately no serverside resource in my application